# Getting a 603 Error using REST API to Create a New Lead from Form

Tags: json, rest, api, marketo

I am trying to pull form fields from a non-marketo form using REST API and wrote this code here:

```
$.ajax({ type: 'GET', url: 
https://106-YPF645.mktorest.com/rest/asset/v1/form/fields.json/ 
?access_token=bfdf9dff-c2c5-45b7-a7e4-3e91e88a46d3:ab', data: '{ "action":   
"createOnly", "input": [ { 
"firstName": "FirstName", 
"lastName": "LastName", 
"Email": "Email", 
"Phone": "Phone", 
"postalCode": "PostalCode", 
"listingID": "ListingID"
} ] }', dataType : 'jsonp', crossDomain:true, success: function(data) { }, contentType: "application/json", dataType: 'json' });
```

but when i test this in hurl.it it gives me this error code 603 Access Denied

Can someone explain what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you access the URL through the browser? Could be that the token is not valid/authorised, need UN and PW.

Comment: Why do you put `data` field with `GET` request? If you want to create field use POST.

Comment: And hostname looks misprinted - `106-YPF645.mktorest.com`. You probably skipped `-` between `YPF` and `645`

Answer (score 0):

According to Marketo [REST API documentation](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/error-codes/) the service account, you use for API, don't have access to form fields.
AFAIK it is in **Assets API -> Read-only assets** or **Read-write assets.**

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is a slash ("/") behind fields.json which shouldn't be there.

You're not making this request client-side, right? Exposing the access_token would be a security risk.